# How to load more than 20 image from instagram?

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

i'm trying to submit my app to get more than 20 image from my instagram account but when trying to edit the app permission and choose the option

```
"I want to display my Instagram posts on my website."
```

but i get this message

```
You do not need to submit for review for this use case.
If you are a developer and you want to display Instagram content on your
website, then you do not need to submit your app for review. By using a
client in sandbox mode, you can still access the last 20 media of any 
sandbox user that grants you permission.

You can find more information in the Permission Review documentation.
```

and in the documentation there is nothing on how to get more than 20 images or how to go live in this case please any help and many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You must submit your app for review.

Go to Manage Clients, then click edit on the APP you want to submit. Then go to the Permission tab and click the green Start a Submission button.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram API documentation is explicit saying that on sandbox you're limited to the 20 recent photos of the sandbox users.

But, before submitting the app for review, you can try using count parameter on url, limited to 33 photos.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN&count=33
```

The other obvius attempt is navigate through pages to get more photos... but I believe you already did it.